# bones animation

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I'm trying to move eyebrow's, nose or mouth but i can't move them. I've animated that parts but now they don´t follow anything. Can you help me, please?

Here is the file
[image]

And the inicial file [image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using L eyebrow as example: the bone which (I think) should move the eyebrow is named "Eyebrow.L":

[image]

While the vertex groups to which the eyebrow vertices are weighted have different names:

[image]

So you can either:

1 - create a vertex group named "Eyebrow.L", select all vertices of the eyebrow and assign a weight of 1.0 to it.

or

2 - create four bones named with the four vertex groups names, for finer control.

Every deforming bone acts to a vertex group which has exactly the same name.

P.S. I noticed that in an hidden layer there is another armature named "brow rig" which contains the eyebrow deforming bones. It seems disconnected from the main rig. You can parent it to the eyebrow bone and use it for deforming.

[image]

Comment: I can't solve this...i've uploaded the inicial file of the eleven ri. i didn't modify any value or vertex group...Can you please take it a look?

Comment: The inicial file is OK, you can append in it your nice animations, just remember to set both arms to IK in the "N" properties panel.